# Unable to read from the Serial Port using PySerial

Tags: python, pyserial

This is my function.  i am trying to send the word **sensors** to the COM Port and then get back the result.

```
def serialportcommunication():
    
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port='COM5',
        baudrate=115200
    )

print('Writing SENSORS command to COM7')
ser.write(b"sensors")
time.sleep(4)

print('Reading 10 bytes from serial buffer')
read_val = ser.read(size=10)
print(read_val)
print('Done printing output')
```

Output I get of the code above:

> Writing SENSORS command to COM7
>
> Reading 10 bytes from serial buffer
>
> b'sensors\r\n '
>
> Done printing output

If I execute the command **"sensors"** to the COM Port using a Terminal Program like Putty, I get a wall of text from my target device (the sample output is shown below, I had to white out most of the output though).

This text I am reading back, I want to read it in Python using teh command above of ser.read(size = ??), but I don't read anything back.

How to read it back?

[MY SCREENSHOT FROM USING PUTTY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZzaW.png)

Comment: You are not writing the word "sensors" anywhere in the code. Use `ser.write(b"sensors")` before `time.sleep(4)`

Comment: you need to write to the serial port first ....

Comment: @HashSplat Just did that but I dont really read anything back. I pasted my output above too.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Am I not writing to the serial port using the ser.write(b"sensors") command?

Comment: Do you have to hit Enter when typing the command manually?  Then you need to do the same here - `ser.write(b"sensors\r")` (or maybe `\n`, or `\r\n`).

Comment: Yes, when i enter the command in Putty, I to hit enter. Thank you thank you. I added the '\n in the end and it works now!!!!

Comment: The other end of the serial port must be using a readline command that waits for a "\n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Resolved in comments:
>
> ```
> Do you have to hit Enter when typing the command manually? Then you need to do the same here - ser.write(b"sensors\r") (or maybe \n, or \r\n). – jasonharper
>
> Yes, when i enter the command in Putty, I to hit enter. Thank you thank you. I added the '\n in the end and it works now!!!! – Neil Dey
> ```